# Please explain the following code snippet?

Tags: android

```
public Boolean isTablet() {

    if ((getResources.getConfiguration.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= 
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I just want to determine if device is in large or x-large category.

isTablet is equivalent to  isLarge_Or_X-large

I am not able to understand why we are taking and of (screenLayout  & 15) >= 3.
What does getResources.getConfiguration.screenLayout means?
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK   : constant value 15
Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE  : constant value 3.

Comment: Have you searched about `CREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK` and `Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE` .?

Comment: I think the function name kind of gives it away, no?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code definition processing center. It is for describing/fixing specific programming problems.

Comment: Is there a part of the code snippet you don't understand, or just the whole thing?

Comment: it is all about to know that which deviceis in current use a tablet or else!!

Comment: Please do not encourage questions like these, they are encouraging poor programming behavior.

Answer (score 0):

please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html

it is all about to know that which deviceis in current use a tablet or else!! with the help of screen layout configurations we are doing the check!!

in this function what we are checking about to configuration about

```
public static final int SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK
```

Added in API level 4
Constant for screenLayout: bits that encode the size.

v/s the

```
public static final int SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
```

Added in API level 4
Constant for screenLayout: a SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK value indicating the screen is at least approximately 480x640 dp units, corresponds to the large resource

which is all about to know that it is tablet device or else!!